# SQL with no matches found causes MsgBox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My form takes the data the user entered, constructs a SQL statement and returns the results. I would like to have a message box pop up when there are no matches found.

My current code/idea:

```
If qdf.sql = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No clients matching your information." & _
        vbCrLf & "have been found. Please try again." & _
        , vbCritical, "No Matches"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSearchResults"
        Me.Visible = False
End If
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax for `if qdf.sql = 0` .

**UPDATE: Full query**

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

'On Error GoTo cmdSearch_Click_err

Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim strClientID As String
Dim strLastName As String
Dim strFirstName As String
Dim strDOB As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(qdf.sql)

' call QueryCheck module to determine if query exists
If Not QueryExists("qrySearch") Then
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("qrySearch")
Else
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qrySearch")
End If

' handle nulls in the user's entries
    If IsNull(Me.txtClientID.Value) Then
        strClientID = " Like '*' "
        Else
        strClientID = "='" & Me.txtClientID.Value & "' "
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.txtLastName.Value) Then
        strLastName = " Like '*' "
        Else
        strLastName = " Like '" & Me.txtLastName.Value & "*' "
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName.Value) Then
        strFirstName = " Like '*' "
        Else
        strFirstName = " Like '*" & Me.txtFirstName.Value & "*' "
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.txtDOB.Value) Then
        strDOB = " Like '*' "
        Else
        strDOB = "='" & Me.txtDOB.Value & "' "
    End If

strSQL = "SELECT Clients.* " & _
         "FROM Clients " & _
         "WHERE Clients.clientid" & strClientID & _
         "AND Clients.namelast" & strLastName & _
         "AND Clients.namefirst" & strFirstName & _
         "AND Clients.birthdate" & strDOB & _
         "ORDER BY Clients.namelast,Clients.namefirst;"

Debug.Print strSQL

' check to see if the results form is open and close if it is
DoCmd.Echo False

If Application.SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, "frmSearchResults") = acObjStateOpen Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSearchResults"
End If

' run SQL statment
qdf.sql = strSQL

' check for no matches found
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No clients matching your information were found." & _
        vbCrLf & "Please search again.", vbInformation, "No Matches"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSearchResults"
        Me.Visible = False
    End If

'cmdSearch_Click_exit:
'    DoCmd.Echo True
'    Set qdf = Nothing
'    Set db = Nothing

'Exit Sub

'cmdSearch_Click_err:
'        MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." & _
'        vbCrLf & "Please note of the following details and contact the EIIS support desk:" & _
'        vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & _
'        vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description _
'        , vbCritical, "Error"
'    Resume cmdSearch_Click_exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `If qdf.sql = 0 then` won't perform a proper check is that `qdf` contains the information about your query such as the SQL text that you are checking in that statement but not the results.

To get the results of the query you need to assign it to a `Recordset` after you have build your query.  So first build your query and then assign it to the record set.

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim qdf as DAO.Querydef
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("qrySearch")

Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qdf.sql)
```

You can then check what your record set has returned.

```
If rs.RecordCount = 0 then
```

So where you have your line `' run SQL statment`  you would want to place the `Set rs` line.

Comment: I'm receiving the error `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`. The set rs line is throwing the error. I've updated my post with the full query if that would be helpful.

Comment: You are receiving this error because you are trying to assign the query def to the recordset before you have opened it or modified the SQL.  You will want to place the `Set rs` line below your line of `qdf.sql = strSQL`

Answer (score 0):

If you have any ADO experience you can use something like

```
dim strSQL as String
dim conn as Connection
dim cmd as Command
dim rs as Recordset
```

*(set up connection/command here)*

```
cmd.commandtext = (your select query)
set rs = Command.execute

if rs.eof then
```

*(or if rs.recordcount = 0 however returning a recordcount                              requires the correct cursortype - usually adOpenStatic - to be used)*

```
'msgbox no match

else
   'do stuff
```

If any of this is alien, then post your actual query and I'll try and give you the code in full. Good luck!